# Multi excel worksheets grab data from 3 cells in each sheet and output as csv

Tags: vba, excel, csv

i haven't used excel in years its took me some time to automate my price sheet for my contract as a self employed electrician

each week when it comes to invoicing it take a while filling the sheets out but then the effort is increased when i am copying and pasting info from 3 cells out of the mass of worksheets to then input into my invoice .

can any kind soul tell me a way i could extract data from every worksheet in the excel file (no matter how many there is as it changes weekly).

the cells i want to extract from each worksheet are a4:c5:e76

and the out out put it in a csv like so (each line represents a worksheet)

```
a4:c5:e76
a4:c5:e76
a4:c5:e76
a4:c5:e76
```

Answer (score 1):

This is only a sample:

```
Sub MakeFile()
    Dim sh As Worksheet
    Dim TextLine As String

    Close #1
    Open "C:\TestFolder\TestFile.csv" For Output As #1

    For Each sh In ActiveWorkbook.Sheets
        TextLine = sh.Range("A3").Text & ":" & sh.Range("C5").Text & ":" & sh.Range("E76").Text
        Print #1, TextLine
    Next sh

    Close #1
End Sub
```

You will need to adjust the filespec to match your folder structure.